# Upgrading Spring Project from 4.2.3.RELEASE to 6.0.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to upgrade my multi module old spring project. Current version is 4.2.3.RELESE and I'm trying to upgrade to latest version 6.0.4.

I'm upgrading all the spring dependencies like spring-bean, spring-context, spring-jdbc, spring-orm etc.

after upgrading when I try to build the project, I'm getting the compilation error which means cannot import/access **SqlRowSet** from spring-jdbc:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Project-Name\src\main\java\com\rest\retest\entity\ads\Test.java:[6,46] error: cannot access SqlRowSet
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
```

Here are my imports

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSetMetaData;

public abstract class Iterator {

    protected SqlRowSet rowSet;

    public void setSqlRowSet(SqlRowSet rowSet) {
        this.rowSet = rowSet;

        SqlRowSetMetaData metaData = rowSet.getMetaData();

        String[] columnNames = metaData.getColumnNames();

        setIndexes(columnNames);
    }
}
```

In the sub module maven dependency folder I'm able to see this complete package and class
`org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet`

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Without having looked into this any further, I would recommend updating only one major version at a time, thus first update to 5.x before migrating to 6.x.

Comment: @Endzeit I'm not facing this issue with 5.x version.
My only concern is to moving higher version like 6.x

Comment: Please post your pom to see if any dependence is not right